# grep with quotes

Tags: python, grep

I need to find such string `Job 'Initialize' completed successfully` and run this command from python.

so shell `grep -c "Job 'Initialize' completed" 1.log`   works fine but how this command will looks in python? `cmd = """grep -c "Job 'Initialize' completed" 1.log"""`?

Comment: what are you attempting to do with cmd in python?

Comment: @Francheska - You should note that you are not creating a shell and executing the `grep` command directly (based on recent comments)

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to do with subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['grep','-c',"Job 'Initialize' completed", '1.log'])
```

Comment: I agree, that's the best way - but I have exteranl function executing comands by ssh and it's expecting cmd to be the string

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Python, then use Python:

```
with open('1.log') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        if "Job 'Initialize' completed" in line:
            count += 1
print "Count: {}".format(count)
```

or

```
with open('1.log') as f:
    count = sum(1 for line in f if "Job 'Initialize' completed" in line)
print "Count: {}".format(count)
```

Comment: I like it more than calling `grep`, but for huge files `grep` is normally significantly faster than a Python code like this.

Comment: 1.log is located on remote host - I thought I need to use ssh?

Answer (score 0):

shell commands can be executed as-in in python with triple-quoting and by passing shell=True to subprocess.call. Note that per the documentation "Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input"

```
 subprocess.call(''' grep -c "Job 'Initialize' completed" 1.log ''', shell=True)
```